# visualforce page display time in timezone

Tags: datetime, configuration

I have a email alert that uses a Visualforce email template to generate an email with a date/time field that I want my to display as GMT, currently the time displayed in the email is offset by the hours credit or deficit based on the timezone of the user that triggered the email alert through a workflow.) What do I need to change in order to rectify this?

```
<p>Date of completion <apex:outputtext value=" {!Relatedto.Completion_Date__c}"/>.</p>
```

Solution:

```
   <apex:outputText value="{0,date,yyyy.MM.dd 'at' HH:mm}">
   <apex:param value="{!Relatedto.Completion_Date__c}}" />
```

^ = 2015.01.06 at 14:43

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Value property of apex:outputText tag to specify the GMT format like this.

```
   <apex:outputText value="The formatted time right now is: 
         {0,date,yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z}">
       <apex:param value="{!NOW()}" />
   </apex:outputText>
```

Comment: Would it look something like what I have put in above as a possible solution?

Comment: I tested that and got it to convert it to GMT which is great, the only thing to note is that it returns the date and time in the format: 2015.01.06 AD at 14:43:00 GMT this is a little unfriendly to the reader.

Comment: The G defines the era (as in AD or BCE) and does not define GMT - see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html. You can remove the `:ss` if you don't want to show seconds. A useful tool is http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/simpledateformat.htm

Comment: how to achieve the same for <apex:input> field

Answer (score 2):

Convert "Data-Time" DataType to "String" and Salesforce Platform automatically takes care of the Time-Zone Conversion to User Specific Time-zone.

[image]

Comment: True that !
thanks for this info  - if we do not want that, am concatenating an empty string  :

string unFormattedDateTime = '' + System.Now();